# From where does dql (dynamic queue limit) variables in kernel get their value?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, ethernet, yocto

### **Context :**

I was working with a custom driver in an arm SoC, while trying `ifconfig enp1s0 up`. I was getting a report like below

```
WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 0 at /home/abc/Yocto_Setup/fsl-release-bsp/build-x11-imx6dlsabresd/tmp/work-shared/imx6dlsabresd/kernel-source/net/schc
NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp1s0 (igb): transmit queue 0 timed out
```

(Only the beginning is included.)

From dmesg I got to know that LINK is going down in between. I started debugging and found that transmission queue is getting timed out so LINK is being reset. Continuing along the road I reached at this point where the problem is caused by a variable in dql(dynamic queue limit) in linux, dql->adj_limit.

```
static inline int dql_avail(const struct dql *dql)
{
        return ACCESS_ONCE(dql->adj_limit) - ACCESS_ONCE(dql->num_queued);
}
```

Here dql->adj_limit is always 0, while dql->num_queued is showing 70. I saw a function in dql library `void dql_completed(struct dql *dql, unsigned int count)`  doing

```
dql->adj_limit = limit + completed;
```

but this function is not been called. Apart from this `dql->adj_limit` is set to zero and not being updated at any part.(As of my findings).

### Question :

**From where does dql variables get their value?**

(Note :
I am not addressing the actual problem because I think its too broad. )

Answer (score -1):

dql variables can be set from nework drivers by making use of the [dql library api's](https://lwn.net/Articles/469651/).

EDIT :
There is this api `netdev_tx_completed_queue` which will update the dql values. I was using a custom igb driver and it was never calling this api. That's why I got transmission timed out messages.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, but could you please edit this and show an example of how you did it so that others with the same problem can understand?